# Css Z-index Under and Over

Tags: html, css

I have a navigation div fixed to the top of the screen, at the top of my page I have a div that takes up the whole screen.

I made the nav div have a z-index of -1, and my div at the top have a z-index of 1. So My nav goes under the div. But then when you scroll down I have another div with a z-index of -2, but my nav still goes under it. Can anyone tell me how to make a fixed nav go under the first element and go over the second?

Hope I made it clear what I was asking and my explanation.

Comment: It is hard to debug without some code. However, my guess is you have a separate stacking context which is complicating the issue. Check out this very helpful article for more information - http://philipwalton.com/articles/what-no-one-told-you-about-z-index/

Answer (score 1):

The problem is related to how the stacking of your elements is calculated.
You just need to add `position: relative` to the div that you want to go under.

With this basic HTML:

```
<div id="nav"></div>
<div id="top"></div>
<div id="next"></div>
<div id="bottom"></div>
```

And this basic CSS:

```
#nav {
    height: 100px;
    width:100%;
    background: red;
    z-index: -1;
    position:fixed;
}

#top {
    height: 400px;
    width:100%;    
    background: white;    
    z-index: 1;
}

#next {
    position: relative;
    height: 100px;
    width:100%;    
    background: blue;    
    z-index: -2;
}

#bottom {
    height: 400px;
    width:100%;    
    background: blue;    
    z-index: -2;
}
```

[Here is the JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/4Ltf3/)

Answer (score 0):

You can solve this problem be adding a inner div with in your nav and add position:relative to that div and it will work perfect

Answer (score 0):

setting the **position:relative** will solve the problem because z-index only works on **positioned elements** (position:absolute, position:relative, or position:fixed)